How can I make multisig DAO in anchor?
I am working on DAO smart contract developing using Rust.
But I can't find any example of DAO in anchor.
Is there any good way?

I would consider getting inspiration about DAO development in the SPL DAO Governance program (under Solana program library, https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/governance/README.md). It's not written in Anchor but is one of the most used in Solana.
Technical doc at: https://docs.realms.today/SPL%20Governance%20Deep%20Dive/splgovernance
On top, there are plugins written in Anchor for the SPL Governance program like Voter Stake Registry (VSR, https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/voter-stake-registry).

Take a look at the TribecaHQ programs, which are Anchor programs to perform DAO operations: https://github.com/TribecaHQ/tribeca

This is a good suggestion but note tribeca seems to be unmaintained - there's no updated for a couple of years and some of the macros like access_control don't exist in current anchor (nor do the docs have any info on what replaced them).
